# Can I change the region of my Google Compute Engine project once it is deployed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I host my node.js app and the MySQL database on Google Compute Engine. However, I would like to change the region of the instance and the whole project to another one, although my web app is fully running right now.

It seems that there is no section that helps me change the region/zone.

Can I still change it after deploying it? Or should I create another project and host the app and database from scratch again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move an instance between zones (even if they are in different regions) by using the [gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) tool.

```
gcloud compute instances move example-instance \
  --zone us-central1-a --destination-zone us-east1-b
```

Comment: This seems the way to go. Only point to take into consideration if you are moving the VM to another region you will not be able to preserve the [IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones).

Comment: Actually you can't move instance across regions using the command. You will get  an error which says Instances belonging to subnetworks cannot be moved interregionally.  Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441423/migrate-google-compute-engine-instance-to-a-different-region)